# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, java, .net

I wrote a very small function to start a Java application in C# NET, but I am getting the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MinecraftDaemon.Program.LaunchMinecraft()' C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Minecraft\MinecraftDaemon\Program.cs". I have searched other threads that suffer from the same issue but I don't understand what it means or why I am getting it.

```
namespace MinecraftDaemon
{
    class Program
    {
        public void LaunchMinecraft()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", "-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui");
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            try
            {
                using (Process minecraftProcess = Process.Start(processInfo))
                {
                    minecraftProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Log Error
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LaunchMinecraft();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is because `LaunchMineCraft` method needs an instance. Or that method should be Static.

Comment: I wonder if a Compiler warning is given for this case? anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
public static void LaunchMinecraft()
```

That way, the static `Main` method can access the static `LaunchMinecraft` method.

Comment: Another option, of course, is to change Main() to new Program().LaunchMinecraft();

Answer (score 4):

`LaunchMinecraft` is not a static method so you cannot access it in the static method `Main` without calling it from the `Program` object.

Two options
 1. Make `LaunchMinecraft` static

```
public void LaunchMinecraft() 
{ ... }
```

2. Create a new `Program` object in `Main` and call it that way.

```
var program = new Program();
program.LaunchMinecraft();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an instance method (ie. a method that needs a specific object to operate on) from a static method (a method that works without a specific object). Make the `LaunchMinecraft` method static as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about C# but the `Main()` method is static, while `LaunchMinecraft()`
 isn't, that's the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Program pg = new Program();
                pg.LaunchMinecraft();

            }
```

Try this.