# An object is required for the non-static method or field error

Tags: c#, jwplayer

```
Type cstype = this.GetType();


        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;  ///Broken line


        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "loadvideo"))
        {
            StringBuilder cstext3 = new StringBuilder();
            cstext3.Append("jwplayer(\"vidplayer\").setup({");
            cstext3.Append("flashplayer:\"./players/player.swf\",");
            cstext3.Append("file: \"");
            cstext3.Append("./video.mp4");
            cstext3.Append("\",height: 270,");
            cstext3.Append("width: 400");
            cstext3.Append("});");
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "loadvideo", cstext3.ToString(), true);
```

There is

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.get'"

error in specified line. How can I fix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861196/asp-net-how-to-call-clientscript-from-public-static-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717498/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property

Comment: Are you trying to embed the player into a Windows phone app or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page.ClientScript` is not a static property, so you cannot use it this way. Assume you have the `Page` instance named as `pageInstance` which can be access in the method, use below instead:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = pageInstance.ClientScript;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got this error now.
"The name 'pageInstance' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: 'pageInstance' should be replaced by the variable name of your Page instance.

Comment: Thank you. There is no error now. I have a question. How do I put this in Form. I want to run jwplayer in this form.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this code is from the page itself, try this instead...

```
ClientScriptManager cs = this.ClientScript;  ///Broken line
```